# Count Expression in Google App Engine Full Text Search

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

How to use `count` expression in Google App Engine?

From [doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview#Building_Queries), it states the following:

- count
- unary
- Returns the total number of attribute values for this document.
- count(size)